# How to replace comma with plus sign using awk

Tags: unix, awk, replace

I have this comma separated number:

```
458,221
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
+458+221
```

I tried with:

```
cat result.txt | awk '{gsub("+",/,/);}'
```

However I'm getting "invalid command code" error.

Comment: its a wierd way of using `awk` !! try `awk '{gsub(/,|^/,"+")}1' result.txt` or `awk '{gsub(/,/,"+")}1' result.txt` .

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: If you are only converting comma to plus ,than why there is additional plus sigh at the start of you desired output. (before 458)

Comment: Yes, I need a prefix `+` sign as well to use it with imagemagic script

Comment: you were using incorrect syntax of `gsub` ,check command #1 answer is already present.

Comment: Using `awk` you are serializing data into code, instead of treating data as data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will Replace `,` and `^` (Start of the line) with anything inside `""` .In this case `+` .

```
awk '{gsub(/,|^/,"+")}1' result.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

To perform a simple substitution, use sed:

```
$ sed 's/^\|,/+/g' <<<'458,221'
+458+221
```

Match the start of the line `^` or a comma `,` and replace all matches with a plus `+`.

Use `sed 's/^\|,/+/g' result.txt` if the text is in a file.

Answer (score 0):

`cat results.txt | tr "," "+" | awk '{printf "+%s\n", $0 }'`

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.